# how to ignore lines when writing to a file

Tags: c++

how can I write to a file at the nth line (for example the 5th line) in c++? 
here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream  stream1("1.txt");
    string line ;
    ofstream stream2("2.txt");
    int lineNumber = 0;

    while(getline( stream1, line ) )
    {
        if (lineNumber == 5)
        {
         stream2 << "Input" << endl;
         lineNumber = 0;
        }

    lineNumber++;
    }       

    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();    return 0;
}
```

in "1.txt", I have the word "Student" at the 4th line, now I want to ignore the above 4 lines and input the word "Input" at the 5th line (below the word "Student"). When I run the above code, the output file is blank. Any suggestion how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What's not working with the code you have?

Comment: my output file (2.txt) is blank.

Comment: Why not try debugging the program? Step through line by line and watch what happens.

Comment: You never write into `stream2` except if you are at line 5, is it possible that your file doesnt have five lines? Should you have seomething like `} else { stream2 << line` ?

Comment: Note that you are dealing with the 6th line here, not the 5th.

Comment: If you only want to write new things at the end of your 1.txt you can open in as: ofstream stream1("1.txt", ios_base::app)  and then just write directly to it. If you want to insert a line in the middle of a file is it replacing a line that is there or placing it before the equivalent line?

Comment: oh I fixed it! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, all you want is a replica of 1.txt in 2.txt with just the specific line number replaced with your personal content.

In your case it seems, the word is "Input".

Well here is a code that I modified from your original one -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream  stream1("1.txt");
    string line ;
    ofstream stream2("2.txt");
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int line_to_replace = 4; //This will replace 5th line

    while(getline( stream1, line ) ) 
    {   
            if (lineNumber == line_to_replace)
            {   
                    stream2 << "Input" << endl;
            }   
            else
                    stream2 << line << endl;

            lineNumber++;
    }    

    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();    
    return 0;
}
```

Input File (1.txt) -

```
sdlfknas
sdfas
sdf
g
thtr
34t4
bfgndty
45y564
grtg
```

Output File (2.txt) -

```
sdlfknas
sdfas
sdf
g
Input
34t4
bfgndty
45y564
grtg
```

p.s. To learn and understand programming better, I would recommend not to use:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: You obviously didn't test this.

Comment: I did.. that seems a bit rude.. What part of it doesn't compile and work..?

Comment: Oh right, @TriHard8... I got it now.
I have corrected my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Is it fine now, @TriHard8..?

Comment: This does the 5th line only, not every 5th line. @badola

Comment: He asked for the 5th line, not every 5th line. I hope, I understood the problem right..

Comment: agreed OP isn't very clear.  I assumed since OP was resetting `lineNumber` to 0 they intended it to go every 5th line.  Until they reply, this should work with that caveat.

Comment: @badola I agree with you on your last statement about `using namespace std;` If you look at my answer below it shows. It is just a train wreck waiting to happen!

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading the 5th line, `lineNumber` equals 4 b/c you start your counting at 0.
Change `if(lineNumber == 5)`
to `if(lineNumber == 4)`  You also have an issue where you're setting `lineNumber = 0` then immediately incrementing to 1, so you're only going to count 4 lines before outputting again.

Comment: the output file is still blank.

Comment: if you're not getting any output then either there's nothing in your 1.txt file, or your `getline` statement isn't working properly, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function like this...

```
bool isBlank(string line) { 
    if (!line.empty()) {
        for (auto x: line) {
            if (isalnum(x)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It returns true if a string is empty or has no alphanumeric characters.

You can call this function right after the getline statement.

The **isalnum** function is specified in `<cctype>`

Answer (score 1):

After working with your code I managed to get the output that you desired. Here is the updated version of your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream stream1( "1.txt" );
    std::string line;
    std::ofstream stream2( "2.txt" );
    int lineNumber = 1;

    while ( getLine( stream1, line ) ) {
        if ( lineNumber == 5 ) {
            stream2 << "Input" << std::endl;

        } else {
            stream2 << std::endl;
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }

    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The one thing you have to make sure is that in your `1.txt` that has the word student on the 4th line is that you must have at least 2 empty lines after this text in the file. A simple enter or carriage return will do! If you do not the `while( getline() )` will go out of scope and it will not read the next line and the code block will never enter your `if()` statement when `lineNumber == 5` and it will not print the text `"Input"` to your `stream2` file stream object.

If your last line of text in your `1.txt` file is the line with the string of text `Student` what happens here is it will add this line of text to your `line` string variable then the code will increment your `lineNumber` to equal `5`. The next time you go into the while loop to call `getline()` it returns false because you are at the `EOF` since there are no more lines of text from the file to read in and this causes the while loop to break out of execution and it goes out of scope and the `if( lineNumber == 5 )` never gets called because it is nested within the `while` loop's scope.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer addressed the issue with your problem and getting the output to your text file appropriately. However as I mentioned about the while loop for reading in a line of text and using the same counter for both file streams is not very elegant. A more accurate way to do this which will also allow for debugging to be simplified would be to read in your full input file one line at a time and save each line into a string while storing your strings in a vector. This way you can parse each line of text that you need one at a time and you can easily traverse your vector to quickly find your line of text. You should also do checks to make sure your file exists and that it opens correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string strTextFileIn( "1.txt" );
    std::ifstream in;
    std::string strLine;
    std::vector<std::string> vFileContents;

    // Open File Stream
    in.open( strTextFileIn.c_str(), std::ios_base::in );
    // Test To Make Sure It Opened Properly And That It Exists
    if ( !in.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file, check to make sure file exists." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } else {
        while ( !in.eof() ) {
            // Get Line Of Text And Save To String
            std::getline( in, strLine );
            // Push String Into Vector
            vFileContents.push_back( strLine );
        }
    }

    // Done With File Close File Stream
    if ( in.is_open() ) {
        in.close();
    }

    // Now That We Have Read In The File Contents And Have Saved Each Line Of Text To A String
    // And Stored It In Our Container (Vector) We Can Traverse Our Vector To Find Which String
    // Matches The Text We Are Looking For Retrive Its Indexed Value And Then Write To Our
    // Output File According To Where You Want The Text To Be Written
    unsigned index = 0;
    const std::string strLookup( "Student" );
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < vFileContents.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( vFileContents[i] == strLookup ) {
             // Strings Match We Have Our Indexed Value
            index = i;
        }
    }

    // We Want To Write Our Line Of Text 1 Line Past Our Index Value As You Have Stated.
    std::string strTextFileOut( "2.txt" );
    std::ofstream out;

    // Open Our File For Writting
    out.open( strTextFileOut.c_str(), std::ios_base::out );
    if ( !out.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Failed To open file.";
        vFileContents.clear();
        return -1;
    } else {
        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= index; i++ ) {
            out << std::endl; // Write Blank Lines
        }
        // The Text Or String You Want To Write To File
        out << "Input" << std::endl;         
    }

    // Done With File Stream
    if ( in.is_open() ) {
        in.close();
    }

    // Clear Out Vector
    vFileContents.clear();

    return 0;
} // main
```

Now this can be simplified a bit more by creating a class hierarchy for working with various file stream object types so that you don't have to write this code to open, close, check validity, read in full file or by line over and over again everywhere you need it. This makes it modular. However this structure relies on a few other classes such as an `ExceptionHandler` class and a `Logger` class. Below is a small multi file application.

**stdafx.h** NOTE: Not all of these includes and defines will be used here, but this is coming from a larger project of mine and I'm stripping out only the classes that are needed here, but leaving my standard header as is. The only contents that I stripped out of this "stdafx.h" is anything that has to deal with OpenGL, OpenAL, Ogg - Vorbis, GLM Libraries & APIs

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#define VC_EXTRALEAN // Exclude Rarely Used Stuff Windows Headers - Windows Only

// Instead of Creating Another File That VS Makes For You "targetver.h"
// I Will Just Append Its Contents Here
#include <SDKDDKVer.h> // Windows Only
#include <Windows.h> // Windows Only
#include <process.h>

#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#include "ExceptionHandler.h"

namespace pro {
enum ReturnCode {
    RETURN_OK = 0,
    RETURN_ERROR = 1,
};

extern const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED;
extern const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED_SHORT;

} // namespace pro

#endif // STDAFX_H
```

**stdafx.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace pro {
    const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED       = static_cast<const unsigned>( -1 );
    const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED_SHORT = static_cast<const unsigned short>( -1 );
} // namespace pro
```

**ExceptionHandler.h**

```
#ifndef EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H
#define EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H

namespace pro {

class ExceptionHandler sealed {
private:
    std::string m_strMessage;

public:
    explicit ExceptionHandler( const std::string& strMessage, bool bSaveInLog = true );
    explicit ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage, bool bSavedInLog = true );
    // ~ExceptionHandler(); // Default Okay
    // ExeptionHandler( const ExceptionHandler& c ); // Default Copy Constructor Okay & Is Needed

    const std::string& getMessage() const;

private:
    ExceptionHandler& operator=( const ExceptionHandler& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // ExceptionHandler

} // namespace pro

#endif // EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H
```

**ExceptionHandler.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ExceptionHandler.h"
#include "Logger.h"

namespace pro {

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::string& strMessage, bool bSaveInLog ) :
m_strMessage( strMessage ) {
    if ( bSavedInLog ) {
        Logger::log( m_strMessage, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
    }
}

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage, bool bSaveInLog ) : 
m_strMessage( strStreamMessage.str() ) {
    if ( bSaveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( m_strMessage, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
    }
} 

const std::string& ExceptionHandler::getMessage() const {
    return m_strMessage;
}

} // namespace pro
```

**BlockThread.h** -- Needed For Logger

```
#ifndef BLOCK_THREAD_H
#define BLOCK_THREAD_H

namespace pro {

class BlockThread sealed {
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION* m_pCriticalSection;

public:
    explicit BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection );
    ~BlockThread();

private:
    BlockThread( const BlockThread& c ); // Not Implemented
    BlockThread& operator=( const BlockThread& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // BlockThread

} // namespace pro

#endif // BLOCK_THREAD_H
```

**BlockThread.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"

namespace pro {

BlockThread::BlockThread( CRTICAL_SECTION& criticalSection ) {
    m_pCriticalSection = &criticalSection;
    EnterCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection );
}       

BlockThread::~BlockThread() {
    LeaveCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection );
}

} // namespace pro
```

**`Logger`** is a **`Singleton`** since you will only want one instance of it while your application is running.

**Singleton.h**

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

namespace pro {

class Singleton {
public:
    enum SingletonType {
        TYPE_LOGGER = 0, // Must Be First!
        // TYPE_SETTINGS,
        // TYPE_ENGINE,
    };

private:
    SingletonType m_eType;
public:
    virtual ~Singleton();

protected:
    explicit Singleton( SingletonType eType );

    void logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const;

private:
    Singleton( const Singleton& c ); // Not Implemented
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Singleton

} // namespace pro

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

**Singleton.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Singleton.h"
//#include "Settings.h"

namespace pro {

struct SingletonInfo {
    const std::string strSingletonName;
    bool              isConstructed;

    SingletonInfo( const std::string& strSingletonNameIn ) :
    strSingletonName( strSingletonNameIn ),
    isConstructed( false ) {}
};

// Order Must Match Types Defined In Singleton::SingletonType enum
static std::array<SingletonInfo, 1> s_aSingletons = { SingletonInfo( "Logger" ) }; /*,
                                                      SingletonInfo( "Settings" ) };*/ // Make Sure The Number Of Types Matches The Number In This Array

Singleton::Singleton( SingletonType eType ) :
m_eType( eType ) {
    bool bSaveInLog = s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_LOGGER ).isConstructed;

    try {
        if ( !s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed ) {
            // Test Initialization Order
            for ( int i = 0; i < eType; ++i ) {
                if ( !s_aSingletons.at( i ).isConstructed ) {
                    throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( i ).strSingletonName + " must be constructed before constructing " + s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName, bSaveInLog );
                }
            }
            s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed = true;

            /*if ( s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_ENGINE ).isConstructed &&
                Setttings::get()->isDebugLogginEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
                logMemoryAllocation( true );
            }*/

        } else {
            throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName + " can only be constructed once.", bSaveInLog );
        }
    } catch ( std::exception& ) {
        // eType Is Out Of Range
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid Singleton Type Specified: " << eType;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream, bSaveInLog );
    }
}

Singleton::~Singleton() {
    /*if ( s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_ENGINE ).isConstructed &&
        Settings::get()->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
        logMemoryAllocation( false );
    }*/

    s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).isConstructed = false;
}

void Singleton::logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const {
    if ( isAllocated ) {
        Logger::log( "Created " + s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).strSingletonName );
    } else {
        Logger::log( "Destroyed " + s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).strSingletonName );
    }
}

} // namespace pro
```

**Logger.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "Singleton.h"

namespace pro {

class Logger sealed : public Singleton {
public:
    // Number Of Items In Enum Type Must Match The Number
    // Of Items And Order Of Items Stored In s_aLogTypes
    enum LoggerType {
        TYPE_INFO = 0,
        TYPE_WARNING,
        TYPE_ERROR,
        TYPE_CONSOLE,
    }; // LoggerType

private:
    std::string m_strLogFilename;
    unsigned    m_uMaxCharacterLength;

    std::array<std::string, 4> m_aLogTypes
    const std::string          m_strUnknownLogType;

    HANDLE m_hConsoleOutput;
    WORD   m_consoleDefualtColor;

public:
    explicit Logger( const std::string& strLogFilename );
    virtual ~Logger();

    static void log( const std::string& strText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );
    static void log( const std::ostringstream& strStreamText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );
    static void log( const char* szText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );

private:
    Logger( const Logger& c ); // Not Implemented
    Logger& operator=( const Logger& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Logger        

} // namespace pro

#endif // LOGGER_H
```

**Logger.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"

#include "TextFileWriter.h"

namespace pro {

static Logger* s_pLogger = nullptr;
static CRITICAL_SECTION = s_criticalSection;

// White Text On Red Background
static const WORD WHITE_ON_RED = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED;

Logger::Logger( const std::string& strLogFilename ) :
Singleton( TYPE_LOGGER ),
m_strLogFilename( strLogFilename ),
m_uMaxCharacterLength( 0 ),
m_strUnknownLogType( "UNKNOWN" ) {
    // Order Must Match Types Defined In Logger::Type enum
    m_aLogTypes[0] = "Info";
    m_aLogTypes[1] = "Warning";
    m_aLogTypes[2] = "Error";
    m_aLogTypes[3] = ""; // Console

    // Find Widest Log Type String
    m_uMaxCharacterLength = m_strUnknownLogType.size();
    for each( const std::string& strLogType in m_aLogTypes ) {
        if ( m_uMaxCharacterLength < strLogType.size() ) {
             m_uMaxCharacterLength = strLogType.size();
        }
    }

    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection ); // Enter Critical Section

    // Start Log File
    TextFileWriter file( m_strLogFilename, false, false );

    // Prepare Console
    m_hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER consoleInfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( m_hConsoleOutput, &consoleInfo );
    m_consoleDefaultColor = consoleInfo.wAttributes;

    s_pLogger = this;

    logMemoryAllocation( true ); 

}

Logger::~Logger() {
    logMemoryAllocation( false );
    s_pLogger = nullptr;
    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
}

void Logger::log( const std::string& strtext, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    log( strText.c_str(), eLogType );
}

void Logger::log( const std::string& strText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    log( strText.str().c_str(), eLogType );
}

void Logger::log( const char* szText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    if ( nullptr == s_pLogger ) {
        std::cout << "Logger has not been initialized, can not log " << szText << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection ); // Enter Critical Section

    std::ostringstream strStream;

    // Default White Text On Red Background
    WORD textColor = WHITE_ON_RED;

    // Chose Log Type Text String, Display "UNKNOWN" If eLogType Is Out Of Range
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( s_pLogger->m_uMaxCharacterLength );

    try {
        if ( TYPE_CONSOLE != eLogType ) {
            strStream << s_pLogger->m_aLogTypes.at( eLogType );
        }
        if ( TYPE_WARNING == eLogType ) {
            // Yellow
            textColor = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if ( TYPE_INFO == eLogType ) {
            // Green
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if ( TYPE_CONSOLE == eLogType ) {
            // Cyan
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        }
    } catch( ... ) {
         strStream << s_pLogger->m_strUnknownLogType;
    }

    // Date And Time
    if ( TYPE_CONSOLE != eLogType ) {
        SYSTEMTIME time;
        GetLocalTime( &time );

        strStream << " [" << time.wYear << "."
                  << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMonth << "."
                  << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wDay << " "
                  << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wHour << ":"
                  << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMinute << ":"
                  << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wSecond << "."
                  << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 3 ) << time.wMilliseconds << "] ";
    }
    strStream << szText << std::endl;

    // Log Message
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->m_hConsoleOutput, textColor );
    std::cout << strStream.str();

    // Save Message To Log File
    try {
        TextFileWriter file( s_pLogger->m_strLogFilename, true, false );
        file.write( strStream.str() );

    } catch( ... ) {
        // Not Saved In Log File, Write Message To Console
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " failed to write to file: " << strStream.str() << std::endl;
    }

    // Reset To Default Color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->m_hConsoleOutput, s_pLogger->m_consoleDefaultColor );

}

} // namespace pro
```

**FileHandler.h** - Base Class

```
#ifndef FILE_HANDLER_H
#define FILE_HANDLER_H

namespace pro {

// class AssetStorage; // Not Used Here

class FileHandler {
protected:
    // static AssetStorage* m_pAssetStorage; // Not Used Here

    std::fstream     m_fileStream;
    std::string      m_strFilePath;
    std::string      m_strFilenameWithPath;

private:
    bool m_bSaveExceptionInLog;

public:
    virtual ~FileHandle();

protected:
    FileHandler( const std::string& strFilename, bool bSaveExceptionInLog );

    void throwError( const std::string& strMessage ) const;
    void throwError( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage ) const;

    bool getString( std::string& str, bool appendPath );

private:
    FileHandler( const FileHandler& c ); // Not Implemented
    FileHandler& operator=( const FileHandler& c ); // Not Implemented      

}; // FileHandler

} // namespace pro

#endif // FILE_HANDLER_H
```

**FileHandler.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FileHandler.h"
// #include "AssetStorage.h" // Not Used Here

namespace pro {

// AssetStorage* FileHandler::m_pAssetStorage = nullptr; // Not Used Here

FileHandler::FileHandler( const std::string& strFilename, bool bSaveExceptionInLog ) :
m_bSaveExceptionInLog( bSaveExceptionInLog ),
m_strFilenameWithPath( strFilename ) {

    /*if ( bSaveExceptionInLog && nullptr == m_pAssetStorage ) {
        m_pAssetStorage = AssetStorage::get();
    }*/ // Not Used Here

    // Extract Path Info If It Exists
    std::string::size_type lastIndex = strFilename.find_last_of( "/\\" );
    if ( lastIndex != std::string::npos ) {
        m_strFilePath = strFilename.substr( 0, lastIndex );
    }

    if ( strFilename.empty() ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " missing filename", m_bSaveExceptionInLog );
    }
}

FileHandler::~FileHandler() {
    if ( m_fileStream.is_open() ) {
         m_fileStream.close();
    }
}

void FileHandler::throwError( const std::string& strMessage ) const {
    throw ExceptionHandler( "File [" + m_strFilenameWithPath + "] " + strMessage, m_bSaveExceptionInLog );
}

void FileHandler::throwError( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage ) const {
     throwError( strStreamMessage.str() );
}

bool FileHandler::getString( std::string& str, bool appendPath ) {
    m_fileStream.read( &str[0], str.size() );
    if ( m_fileStream.fail() ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Trim Right
    str.erase( str.find_first_of( char( 0 ) ) );

    if ( appendPath && !m_strFilePath.empty() ) {
        // Add Path If One Exists
        str = m_strFilePath + "/" + str;
    }

    return true;
}

} // namespace pro
```

Now for the two inherited classes that you have been waiting for to handle File Streams. These Two are Strictly Text. Others within my project are TextureFiles, ModelObjectFiles, etc. I will be showing only the TextFileReader & TextFileWriter.

**TextFileReader.h**

```
#ifndef TEXT_FILE_READER_H
#define TEXT_FILE_READER_H

#include "FileHandler.h"

namespace pro {

class TextFileReader : public FileHandler {
private:
public:
    explicit TextFileReader( const std::string& strFilename );
    // virtual ~ TextFileReader(); // Default Okay

    std::string readAll() const;
    bool        readLine( std::string& strLine );

private:
    TextFileReader( const TextFileReader& c ); // Not Implemented
    TextFileReader& operator=( const TextFileReader& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // TextFileReader

} // namespace pro

#endif // TEXT_FILE_READER_H
```

**TextFileReader.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TextFileReader.h"

namespace pro {

TextFileReader::TextFileReader( const std::string& strFilename ) :
FileHandler( strFilename, true ) {
    m_fileStream.open( m_strFilenameWithPath.c_str(), std::ios_base::in );
    if ( !m_fileStream.is_open() ) {
        throwError( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " can not open file for reading" ) );
}

std::string TextFileReader::readAll() const {
    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << m_fileStream.rdbuf();
    return strStream.str();
}

bool TextFileReader::readLine( std::string& strLine ) {
    if ( m_fileStream.eof() ) {
        return false;
    }
    std::getline( m_fileStream, strLine );
    return true;
}

} // namespace pro
```

**TextFileWriter.h**

```
#ifndef TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H
#define TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H

#include "FileHandler.h"

namespace pro {

class TextFileWriter : public FileHandler {
private:
public:
    TextFileWriter( const std::string& strFilename, bool bAppendToFile, bool bSaveExceptionInLog = true );

void write( const std::string& str );

private:
    TextFileWriter( const TextFileWriter& c ); // Not Implemented
    TextFileWriter& operator=( const TextFileWriter& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // TextFileWriter

} // namespace pro

#endif // TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H
```

**TextFileWriter.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

namespace pro {

TextFileWriter::TextFileWriter( const std::string& strFilename, bool bAppendToFile, bool bSaveExceptionInLog ) :
FileHandler( strFilename, bSaveExceptionInLog ) {
    m_fileStream.open( m_strFilenameWithPath.c_str(),
        std::ios_base::out | ( bAppendToFile ? std::ios_base::app : std::ios_base::trunc ) );

    if ( !m_fileStream.is_open() ) {
        throwError( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " can not open file for writing" ) );
    }
}

void TextFileWriter::write( const std::string& str ) {
    m_fileStream << str;
}

} // namespace pro
```

Now to see a sample of this in action. If you look in the `Logger` class you will already see a use of the TextFileWriter.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "TextFileReader.h"
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

int _tmain( int iNumArguments, _TCHAR* pArgumentText[] ) {
    using namespace pro;

    try {
        // This Is Using The TextFileWriter & Console Output
        // Logger::TYPE_INFO is by default!
        Logger logger( "logger.txt" ); 
        logger.log( "Some Info" );
        logger.log( "Error!", Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
        logger.log( "Warning!", Logger::TYPE_WARNING );

        TextFileReader textReaderSingle( "logger.txt" );
        TextFileReader textReaderAll( "logger.txt" );

        std::string strTextSingle;
        std::string strTextAll;

        textReaderSingle.readLine( strTextSingle );
        std::cout << "Read Single Line: << std::endl << strText << std::endl << std::endl;

        strTextAll = textReaderAll.readAll();
        std::cout << "Read All: " << std::endl << strTextAll << std::endl;

        //Check The logger.txt that was generated in your projects folder!

        std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
        _getch();

    } catch ( ExceptionHandler& e ) {
        std::cout << "Exception Thrown: " << e.getMessage() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
        _getch();
        return RETURN_ERROR;

    } catch( ... ) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " Caught Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
        _getch();
        return RETURN_ERROR;
    }

    return RETURN_OK;
}
```

A majority of this work is accredited to Marek A. Krzeminski, MASc at [www.MarekKnows.com](http://www.marekknows.com). In essence all of these class objects are his; the only major difference is I used my own `namespace pro` as opposed to his. Both `main` functions are of my own work, the first stand alone and the second using his library code.

This is a project that has been in the works for a few years now and most of my advanced knowledge of the C++ language is due to following his video tutorials. This current project is a fairly large scale professional quality GameEngine using Shaders in OpenGL. All of this has been typed and debugged by hand while following along his tutorials.

As a major note; I had also hand typed a majority of this here as well, if this does not compile correctly it may be due to typographical errors. The source it self is a working application. What you see here is a very small percentage of his works! I am willing to accept the credit as to answer this person's question with the accumulation of this knowledge but I can not accept credit for this as being my own work in order to protect Marek and his copyright materials.

With this kind of setup it is quite easy to create your own file parsers and multiple file parsers for different types of files. As I stated above there are two other classes inherited from `FileHandler` that I did not show. If you would like to see more of this project, please vist [www.MarekKnows.com](http://www.marekknows.com) and join the community.